# Content Sliding

Tags: jquery

I have this mark up.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="home">...</section>
<section id="about">...</section>
<section id="page">...</section>
```

How can I animate my content?? when about link is clicked the home section moves left and disappear, then about section comes from the right, and about the page section this animation continues. consider that I want to have the reverse animation, too i.e. when s.b click home again the animation reverse and show the home section again..

thanks in advance

Comment: Check jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Comment: Question is tagged 'jQuery', yet there is no jQuery mentioned in the question.  This site is about _specific_ programming questions, not _here's what I want, so give me the code_.

Comment: Questions written like this make it seem like you are wanting us to do all the work for you. Please provide what you have tried so far and we can help guide you, but don't expect the community to write all your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for what is called a [Coda Slider Effect](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html), which Remy Sharp has a tutorial on at [jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/).